# Formatted UUID from HSQLDB

Tags: hsqldb

Using HSQLDB, when I try,

```
VALUES (UUID())
```

i get unformatted UUID i.e `qqqq345623457612`. Is there a statement where I can get formatted uuid?

Answer (score 0):

When the UUID function is called with a binary UUID argument, it converts it to a formatted string. When used with VALUES, a cast is also required:

```
VALUES CAST(UUID(UUID() ) AS CHAR(34))

CALL UUID(UUID())
```